# Snapshot isolation level error in SQL 2014: Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, isolation-level

We have a Purge procedure which runs daily. We use snapshot isolation level. Suddenly we are getting an error

> Error 3960 - Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict. You cannot use snapshot isolation to access table 'dbo.SXAVWFInboundEventQueue' directly or indirectly in database 'PROD' to update, delete, or insert the row that has been modified or deleted by another transaction. Retry the transaction or change the isolation level for the update/delete statement.

Below is the code in the procedure.

```
UPDATE ie 
SET ContextDetailID = NULL 
from sxavwfinboundeventqueue ie 
     INNER JOIN #ContextDetailWFInstanceTable TBL on ie.ContextDetailID = TBL.ContextDetailID
```

Should we use a subquery instead of this?

```
UPDATE sxavwfinboundeventqueue 
SET ContextDetailID = NULL 
where ContextDetailID in (select ContextDetailID from  #ContextDetailWFInstanceTable)
```

The temp table has below structure

```
CREATE TABLE #ContextDetailWFInstanceTable  
(
  ContextDetailID bigint not null,
  index #ContextDetailWFInstanceTableIndex clustered (ContextDetailID)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the same execution plan with either technique so you'll probably still get the concurrency violation when an attempt is made to modify a row that was changed while the update statement is running.

If you are updating many rows, try batching the update to reduce the likelihood of the concurrency conflict:

```
DECLARE @RowsUpdated int = -1;
WHILE @RowsUpdated <> 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP(1000) ie 
    SET ContextDetailID = NULL 
    FROM sxavwfinboundeventqueue ie 
    INNER JOIN #ContextDetailWFInstanceTable TBL ON ie.ContextDetailID = TBL.ContextDetailID;

    SET @RowsUpdated = @@ROWCOUNT;
END;
```